# Regression OLS estimator with $x_t=1/t$

Tags: econometrics, self-study, time-series

I found some questions in a book and wanted to train for my upcoming exam (expect to see some more posts from me idk), anyhow this is the question.
[image]

To solve point A I rewrote the whole equation in matrix form, realizing that at any $t$, $x_t$ remains the same geometric series $ \left(\displaystyle 1,\frac{1}{2}, \ldots, \frac{1}{T}\right)$. Now, I used this fact to compute the OLS assumption one for weak exogeneity using $E[y_t]$  and $E[y_tx_t]$ (from the last one I get $E[e_tx_t]$ which is equal 0 proving the LSA1). Using the assumptions I simply say that the OLS estimator is non biased and it's consistent using the formula proven in the book itself when the assumptions are not violated.

Is this correct? Did I do something crazy I shouldn't have? Also, I realize that in point b nothing changes when $x_t = \frac{1}{2}$ so I'm not entirely sure. If not, what should I do?

Comment: You can do the algebra directly. The OLS estimator is $\sum_t x_t y_t / \sum_t x_t^2 = \beta + \sum_t x_t e_t / \sum_t x_t^2$. Now substitute $1/t$ for $x_t$ for (a) and $1/2$ for $x_t$ for (b). Unbiasedness is straightforward. For consistency, check if the variance converges to 0. Answer: (a) yes, no; (b) yes, yes; I guess.